# bash autocomplete seemingly hangs

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Consider the following very simple bash autocompletion specification.

```bash
#/usr/bin/env bash

_foo ()
{
  local cur="${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}"

  # The following line, when uncommented, results in broken behavior
  local suggestions=($(compgen -W "$(./foo)" -- "$cur"))

  # When the line above is commented out and the following line is uncommented, we get expected autocomplete behavior.
  # local suggestions=('aaaa' 'bbbb' '--help')

  echo -e "\n@@@ have ${#suggestions[@]} suggestions: ${suggestions[@]}"
  COMPREPLY=("${suggestions[@]}")
}

complete -F _foo foo
```

When the above uses an external script to generate the autocomplete options using a simple `echo "aaaa bbbb --help"` online script stored in `./foo`, then autocompletion seems to not work. When I type `./foo [TAB]` I see the expected `@@@ have 3 suggestions: aaaa bbbb --help`. However, when I then press the second [TAB], only whitespace are printed to the output rather than the expected list of the three choices.

Conversely, when I instead declare the three choices inside my autocompletion script, I get the expected behavior. When I type `./foo [TAB]` I see the expected `@@@ have 3 suggestions: aaaa bbbb --help`. Next, when I press the second [TAB], I see another line with `@@@ have 3 suggestions: aaaa bbbb --help` followed by the expected three choices `--help  aaaa    bbbb` on their own line.

Why isn't autocompletion script able to process the same choices when they are returned by my one-line script?

Comment: This is obviously a fork optimization bug; if you do `$(bash ./foo)` instead, or put `exec echo "aaaa bbbb --help"` inside `./foo` it works as expected. Consider filing a bug report with bug-bash@gnu.org.

Comment: @pynexj - my `./foo` is already executable. If it wasn't, hitting the [TAB] would print an error. My `echo -e` is not a problem either. it is something I added for debugging purposes only. The same behavior exists without it as well.

Comment: @oguzismail - thank you! explicitly calling `./foo` with `bash` did the trick. Interestingly enough, what also does the trick is to change the shebang line in `./foo` from `#/usr/bin/env bash` to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @oguzismail - This is not a bug in bash. The problem is the shebang line in both auto-completion and ./foo scripts. The shebang line was missing the `!`. By putting that in, everything behaves as expected!

Comment: I reported this bug here https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2024-01/msg00101.html and the fix is available here https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?h=devel&id=10702735a0eaeb930e79717d370549b73e3df7af